# Drag and drop connected flowchart elements using native HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I want to create a mapping/flowchart so that the elements of the mapping/chart can be dragged and dropped freely over a canvas. The various units of the chart will be connected and these connections should also stay intact obviously. Is there any way to do this using native HTML5 elements? No external party libraries I mean. I have already had a look at [Plumb.js](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/home/jquery.html) and other such libraries and was wondering if i could implement the same thing in a much simpler manner using just native HTML5 draggable options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

here is another good project :

http://www.graphdracula.net/

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at the source.